# ASP.NET: CheckBox in Page hidden by UserControl does not stay checked when made visible again

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, viewstate

Here's the setup.  I have an ASP.NET4 Page with viewstate enabled, with a RadioButtonList with 2 radio buttons, a CheckBox, and an included UserControl.  I want to hide the CheckBox if one radio button is selected, and show it if the other is selected.  I want the CheckBox to maintain it's state when it is hidden and re-shown; if it was checked before hiding, when it is shown again I still want it to be checked.

The twist is that the code to show/hide the CheckBox, based on what radio button is chosen, lives in the OnPreRender event of the UserControl.  So it does Parent.FindControl()s to get the controls, then hides/shows the CheckBox based on the state of the RadioButtonList.

The issue is, when doing this logic in OnPreRender() of the UserControl, the checkbox does not maintain its state after it is hidden, then reshown.  That is, if the checkbox is checked, then I click the radio button to hide it, when I click the other radio button I want the checkbox to still be checked when it is now shown.  I have a feeling I'm not understanding some of the view state mechanisms, but when I tried adding a TextBox and hiding/showing it, it did maintain it's text value as expected.

I can move the logic to Page_Load of the UserControl and the checkbox state behaves as expected.  But I'm trying to get it to work in OnPreRender(), or at least looking for an explanation as to why I'm seeing this behavior.

In default.aspx:

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="uxRadio" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text="choice 1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="choice 2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="choice 3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="uxCheck" AutoPostBack="true" />
    <uc1:Control ID="uxControl" runat="server"></uc1:Control>
```

UserControl.ascx.cs:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
   RadioButtonList rb = (RadioButtonList)Parent.FindControl("uxRadio");
   CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)Parent.FindControl("uxCheck");

   if (rb.SelectedValue == "2")
   {
       cb.Visible = false;
   }
   else
   {
       cb.Visible = true;
   }
   base.OnPreRender(e);
 }
```

Comment: Please show us some code. Why is the code to show/hide the CheckBox in the UserControl and not in the Page?

Comment: Moving the show/hide code to the Page is an option, but for various legacy reasons the logic exists where it is.  At this point I'm actually more interested in why this behavior occurs given the current setup, even if the only solution is to move the logic.  It just seems odd that a TextBox in the same scenario does not appear to behave the same as the CheckBox.

Comment: without any sourcecode i can only guess, the scenario you mentioned would not cause a ViewStat issue, hence i assume that something is wrong with your logic. Are you setting the Checkbox-Checked state somewhere else(f.e. a missing PostBack check)?

Comment: you could use the curly-braces(code-sample-button)to format added source code.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter Thanks, I suppose I should have tested out posting code before trying it here.  In any case, as you can see it's seemingly pretty straightforward code.  It my application there is certainly more code around it, but I created this simple test page to try to distill down the issue and it still occurs.

Comment: Although this scenario is really weird and i would strongly recommend to move this code to the page(what is when this UC is used inside of a page without these controls?), i'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i could reproduce this issue but i'm not 100% sure why the ViewState is not retained.

I assume that something like this happens:

ASP.NET retrieves the checked-state from CheckBoxes from the posted request but only if it's Visible on serverside(otherwise it wouldn't even be rendered as html). If it's invisible it gets the checked-state from ViewState.

I think that the UserControl's PreRender is too late in this case. ASP.NET does not know that it has to save this value in ViewState because the condition(Visible-State) is changed afterwards. Hence there is no posted value and no ViewState value and ASP.NET must use the default-state(unchecked).

If you move this code from PreRender to Page_Load it  works.

But i would strongly recommend to move it to the Page itself because it really belongs there. A usercontrol should not insist on the existence of specific controls in it's page because it should also work in other pages.

Comment: Yeah, certainly moving the logic to the Page is the best solution, and what I'm going to do.  Again, this has become more a question of why this occurs, especially since a textbox does not seem to exhibit the same behavior (a textbox does seem maintain its state).  In any case, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Rob G: have a look at following exhausting, interesting article about ViewState: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/aspnetviewstatepagecycle.aspx Yyou might be abe to extract the relevant information.